# Asp.net Check box toggle option select 1 only

Tags: jquery, asp.net, input, toggle

I have 3 toggle options that at the minute and I want to only select 1 option at a time.

I have tired a number of functions to try and achieve only 1 to be selected.

I'm still able to click all 3.

Function beging used .

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('input.chkClass').on('change', function () {
        $('input.chkClass').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
</script>
```

Toggle Options.

```
<div id="Div7" visible="false" runat="server">
                <div class="col-md-10 input-group input-group-lg" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="I know how much I spend on Electric"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-style="slow" data-on="Yes" data-off="No" id="Elec_Spend_Toggle" runat="server" class="chkClass" />
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="col-md-10 input-group input-group-lg" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="I know how much Electric I use"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-style="slow" data-on="Yes" data-off="No" id="Elec_Usage_Toggle" runat="server" class="chkClass" />
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="col-md-10 input-group input-group-lg" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label16" runat="server" Text="I DONT know how much Electric I use"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-style="slow" data-on="Yes" data-off="No" id="Elec_DONT_Toggle" runat="server" class="chkClass" />
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="col-md-10 input-group input-group-lg" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                    <asp:Button ID="Continue_5_btn" runat="server" Text="Continue" class="btn btn-primary" Width="150" OnClick="Continue_btn_Click_5" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

I want all these 3 to be linked so if i choose one the other two toggles revert back to No if yes has been selected.

Comment: Any reason you are using jQuery 1.11 instead of 3.x?

Comment: it is working, if it is used in plain html

Comment: Instead of trying to re-invent radio button groups, why don't you use the html input "radio" groups and just style them as toggles.  Plenty of examples online.